# Validate user login through JS and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

im not sure how to go about it but want to validate user login through:

```
<form onsubmit="return validateLogIn()" > and

<script>       
function validateLogIn()
{
  $.ajax({                                      
  url: 'login.php',    //checking the login in                     
  data: "",                      
  dataType: 'json',                  
  success: function(data)          
  {
       continue to crud.html
  } 
  else do an alert("please lgo in again");
 }); 
}
</script>
```

will i have something like the above?

Comment: Yes. Your `login.php` will contain all the login validations and you must return a json encoded flag value based on the validations.

Comment: thanks was not sure im on the right track

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
<script>       
function validateLogIn()
{

  var username  = $("#IdOfYourUserFiled").val();
  var password  = $("#IdOfYourPasswordFiled").val();
  $.ajax({                                      
  url: 'login.php',    //checking the login in                     
  data: {username:username,password:password}, //You have to pass user inputs to next page to validate in DB            
  type: "POST",     //Method by which data being transmitted
  dataType: 'json',                  
  success: function(data)          
  {
       continue to crud.html
  } 
  else do an alert("please lgo in again");
 }); 
}
</script>
```

At login.php to access values of username and password

Use

```
$_POST['username'] and $_POST['password']
```

and write query.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use `beforeSend()` to validate before sending data.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'login.php',
    data:{username:user,password:pass},
    dataType:'json',
    beforeSend:function(xhr){
        if(user.length<7||pass.length<7){
            xhr.abort();//stop process.
            //validation failed etc
        }
     },
     success:function(result){

     }
 });
```

Comment: Whilst it is good to prompt a user before they hit the submit button of potential errors, you should also validate the users data on the server side as well.

Comment: Yep :) specially with images and passwords of such :d

Answer (score -1):

Try below coding,

```
function validateLogIn()
{
  username=$("#name").val();
  password=$("#word").val();
  $.ajax({                                      
  url: 'login.php',    //checking the login in                     
  data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,                     
  dataType: 'json',                  
  success: function(data)          
  {
       if(data === 0){
            alert("Username or Password is incorrect");
        } else if (data == 1){
            window.open('index.php', '_self');  
        }
  } 
 }); 
}
```